# concat result of groupby pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am raising this question for learning a new method for myself.

I have a dataframe like below,

```
    ID  Value
0    1     10
1    1     12
2    1     14
3    1     16
4    1     18
5    2     32
6    2     12
7    2     -8
8    2    -28
9    2    -48
10   2    -68
11   3     12
12   3      1
13   3     43
```

I want to convert this into:

```
    ID  Value  ID  Value   ID  Value
0  1.0   10.0   2     32  3.0   12.0
1  1.0   12.0   2     12  3.0    1.0
2  1.0   14.0   2     -8  3.0   43.0
3  1.0   16.0   2    -28  NaN    NaN
4  1.0   18.0   2    -48  NaN    NaN
5  NaN    NaN   2    -68  NaN    NaN
```

one way to solve this,

print

```
pd.concat([df[df['ID']==1].reset_index(drop=True),df[df['ID']==2].reset_index(drop=True),df[df['ID']==3].reset_index(drop=True)],axis=1)
```

But I'm thinking can I do the same `concat` operation for each groupby method result instead of filtering by value?

Any better/new approaches are more appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup, very possible and quite simple with `pd.concat`, in fact.

```
df = pd.concat({k : g.reset_index(drop=True) for k, g in df.groupby('ID')}, axis=1)
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)
```

Or, a minor variation in Dark's (now deleted) answer (which does not give you the opportunity to specify column suffixes automatically) -

```
pd.concat([g.reset_index(drop=True) for _, g in df.groupby('ID')], axis=1)
```

```
df 
    ID  Value  ID  Value   ID  Value
0  1.0   10.0   2     32  3.0   12.0
1  1.0   12.0   2     12  3.0    1.0
2  1.0   14.0   2     -8  3.0   43.0
3  1.0   16.0   2    -28  NaN    NaN
4  1.0   18.0   2    -48  NaN    NaN
5  NaN    NaN   2    -68  NaN    NaN
```

Those column names are terrible, though. Rather than dropping the first level, you should consider concatenating them to form a pre/suf-fix for the second level. That should be a good exercise for you with `df.columns.map`.

Comment: Ah I was close :0

Comment: @Dark they were different enough that it isn't an issue. :) Anyway, your take on it was good, so I've added that in as an option here.

Comment: @coldspeed , Daek - I was looking for this only. Thank you guys. Do you if i ask one more question related to this?

Comment: @MohamedThasinah if it's close enough to this one, then ask away. Otherwise, you should consider opening another Q ;)

Comment: @coldspeed - What will be the best way to solve this problem (considering performance). let me know should I raise a new question or not?

Comment: @MohamedThasinah you are trying to concatenate groups together. There itself you have no option but to use a groupby. In terms of concatenation, concat is usually your best bet. So, with pandas, this is your best option. There may be a faster option with numpy that's implemented with like 50 lines of code and only makes sense for data > 100000 records, but you'd probably need to slap a bounty of 200+ for someone to be bothered to post it!